# ember.js - Create ArrayProxy in model hook

Tags: ember.js

I am creating an ArrayProxy in the model hook of a route:

```
App.SomeRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: ->
    App.SomeArrayProxy.create()
```

Do I need to destroy this ArrayProxy in the deactivate hook of the route or will ember take care of destroying the model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are responsible for doing clean up on the model. Frequently, you model is a record from an identity map that you don't want to destroy/unload. But in your case, you may want to clean up the ArrayProxy. e.g.

```
deactivate: function(){
   this.controllerFor('some').set('model', null)
   this.currentModel = null;
}
```